# How do I compile a cmake base project with OpenMP dependencies on OS-X?

Tags: cmake, clang, openmp

I am trying to build an [open-source project|https://github.com/openMVG/openMVG] with OpenMP support. However, I am doing so on a mac, and therefore I don't have native OpenMP support.

There are numerous OpenMP Clang projects out there (http://openmp.llvm.org/ and https://clang-omp.github.io/).

My question is, how do I configure my system so that the open source project requires little to no modification to compile with OpenMP support?

Answer (score 0):

Normally cmake would auto discover what compiler to use, then check it against the requirements set by the project - e.g. check for openmp support - and then write a Makefile. You can tell it what compiler to use by either specifying the variables `CC` and `CXX` before the call to `cmake` or by passing the flags `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`. The project requires no changes to make this work.

Normally you could use homebrew to get an openmp-supporting compiler: clang-omp or gcc (real, not apple's). Then you would configure the project specifying your compilers. In this case clang-omp won't work because the build scripts assume you will be linking against `libgomp`, so go with gcc-5:

```
git clone openMVG
cd openMVG
git submodule update --init
mkdir build_dir && cd build_dir
CC=gcc-5 CXX=g++-5 cmake ../src
```